# What is the easiest way to break input boxes into columns?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble finding a simple way to break input boxes into columns. If I have:

First Name
Last Name
Email
Phone
Message

How can I make it so first and email are in the left column, last and phone are in the right column, and messages occupies both?

What I've tried:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Fixed Header and Nav</title>
    <link href="css/HIT.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="#"></a>Intel</h1>
        </div><!--logo-->

        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!--nav-->

    </div><!--container-->  
    </div><!--header-->

    <div class="container">
    <div class="content">

        <form action="operations/create_hit.php" method="post">
            <label class="box">Name</label>
                <input id="hitName" type="text" ><br>
            <label class="box">Title</label>
                <input id="hitTitle" type="text"><br>
            <label class="box">Description</label>
                <input id="hitDescription" type="text"><br>
            <label class="box">Reward</label>
                <input id="hitReward" type="text" ><br>
            <label class="box">External Question URL</label>
                <input id="hitURL" type="text"><br>
            <label class="box">Assignment Duration</label>
                <input id="hitDuration" type="text"><br>
            <label class="box">Assignment Lifetime</label>
                <input id="hitLifetime" type="text"><br>
            <label class="box">AutoApproval Delay</label>
                <input id="hitApprovalDelay" type="text"><br>
            <label class="box">Max Assignments</label>
                <input id="hitMaxAssignments" type="text"><br>  
        </form>

        <input id="submitButton" type="submit">

    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what you did yet? any code ?

Comment: please share your markup and style

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add it. Also I can't figure out how to get my submit button to go back to a not ludicrous size.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/195ee610216f40939d0f

Comment: I've edited the code into your question. If you disagree, you can roll it back. To roll back, click on the "edited ... ago" link - this takes you to the edit history where you will find the rollback option. To edit further, click on the "edit" link below your post. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.half {
 width: 50%;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input class="half" style="float: left;">
<input class="half" style="float: right;">
<input>
```

Comment: i may have input this wrong. this is only moving the boxes to the right, not having side by side columns.

Comment: It's worth noting that you may also need to set the "vertical-align" property for this style of layout.